# Sending Push Notification Subscription Info from Web App to Server Securely

Tags: javascript, push-notification

Once a user subscribes to push notifications, I get the subscription info in my JavaScript code. I want to send this information to the server for storage to be used for future notifications.

I assume that the endpoint for the AJAX POST request should be public (the website itself is publicly accessible). Should the endpoint be completely open? Should I use some token generated on the server that expires after a certain period of time?

My concern is that, if it's open, it can be used maliciously to post data to my server. Should there be some validation of the data? If so, what kind of validation applies to subscription JSON objects?

What's the best practice for doing this securely (if any)?

Comment: Of course you should validate the data, and of course it has to be "open" otherwise you can't (really) POST to it from a device

Comment: @Luca That's what I figured. Any best practices on validation of the subscription data? For instance, is there a way to check if the endpoint is valid?